# ffmpeg throwing "errorMessage": "spawn ffmpeg ENOENT"

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, gulp, executable

My ffmpeg function thats running as a shell command isnt working.  I think its because 'ffmpeg' isnt really referring to anything.  I have the ffmpeg node module in my bundle, but i dont know the execFile command is referring to it here.

Im following [aws-lambda-ffmpeg](https://github.com/binoculars/aws-lambda-ffmpeg) as an example of how to call this particular function. They are referring to 'ffmpeg' as a 64-bit linux build they created from [John Vansickle's static FFMPEG builds](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) in their gulp function.

I want to know how to replace 'ffmpeg' with something that will just recognize it like a node_module without having to do the whole gulp static build process. To my understanding the only reason they are doing that is to get the latest build which i really dont need.

If I am wrong and a static build using gulp is needed for another reason please let me know.

```
function ffmpegProcess(description, cb) {
console.log('Starting FFmpeg');

child_process.execFile(
    'ffmpeg',
    [
        '-y',
        '-loglevel', 'warning',
        '-i', 'download',
        '-c:a', 'copy',
        '-vf', scaleFilter,
        '-movflags', '+faststart',
        '-metadata', 'description=' + description,
        'out.' + config.format.video.extension,
        '-vf', 'thumbnail',
        '-vf', scaleFilter,
        '-vframes', '1',
        'out.' + config.format.image.extension
    ],
    {
        cwd: tempDir
    },
    function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('FFmpeg done.');
        return cb(err, 'FFmpeg finished:' + JSON.stringify({ stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr}));
    }
);
}
```

Comment: If you run an `ffmpeg` command from a command prompt, does it work? What OS is this?

Comment: Im using it in my aws lambda function.  So linux i believe.  I got this code to work by including a ffmpeg executable file but its extremely slow

Comment: @ian please provide me any solution i got a same error on with aws lambda function